# PL/SQL - Can't find my local variable

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am so confused right now; I'm working on a script to find all roles that a user is inherting from. It's very much a work in progress and due to my lack of understanding of PLSQL there's not exactly a lot of progress if you know what I mean.

```
-- Declaration of Table Type
create or replace TYPE TEST 
AS TABLE OF VARCHAR(30);

-- Function here
create or replace FUNCTION FINDPARENTS 
(
  ROLENAME IN VARCHAR2 
) 
    RETURN TEST 
    IS
    tt_t TEST;

BEGIN
    DECLARE
        results test;
        toadd test := TEST(ROLENAME);
        counter number;
        elements number:=1;
    BEGIN
        SELECT GRANTED_ROLE 
        BULK COLLECT INTO toadd 
        FROM DBA_ROLE_PRIVS 
        WHERE GRANTEE = rolename; 

        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        INTO ELEMENTS 
        FROM toadd; -- Error here.
    --(for i in 0 .. ELEMENTS) SELECT FINDPARENTS(ROLE_NAME) FROM DUAL UNION RESULT ... or something.
    END;
END;
```

This code results in the "Table or View not found" error because "toadd" can't be found in the second line (Select Count(*)...) although it can be found in the statement above (Select GRANTED_ROLE...) How is that even possible ?

Also, what's the best way to achieve the recursion? My function returns a Table of VARCHAR, how do I get it to "resolve" every one of those role_names until the role does not have a parent role anymore?

Comment: For your second question, please do refer to https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:853427230099

Comment: really two questions should be two posts, but as the first one was so quick to answer I've given you a bonus solution for the second one ;)

Comment: By the way, you don't need that `BEGIN DECLARE` or one of the `END` keywords. Also, a collection has a `count` method so you don't need SQL to find out how many elements it has.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`toadd` is a variable. We can't use those in a FROM clause, only tables. However, because it's declared as a nested table type we can cast it to a table with a `table()` function:

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) 
    INTO ELEMENTS 
    FROM table(toadd);
```

To answer the other part of the question, Oracle has some neat hierarchical syntax. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/queries003.htm#SQLRF52332).

So you can get a list of all the directly or indirectly granted roles like this:

```
select granted_role
bulk collect into tt_t
from dba_role_privs 
connect by granted_role = prior grantee
start with granted_role = 'ROOT'
/
```

Use the BULK COLLECT syntax when populating a collection.

Comment: Great advice from APC, as usual. One minor addendum regarding BULK COLLECT: the select bulk collect into formulation is perfectly fine for relatively small datasets. But if you use it with a large number of rows, you could end consuming too much PGA memory. So best to use an explicit cursor, then simple loop with fetch-bulk collect, with LIMIT clause. Here's a LiveSQL script with an example: https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_DUT0KQ710EOQ5DO5TAVYUU904.html

Comment: @stevenfeuerstein - I would really worry about the OP's security model if their hierarchy of granted roles was large enough to blow the session memory limits ;-) But in broaderl usage you're right of course.

Comment: Hierarchical syntax? Oh my god, thank you so much for telling me :D I really thought I was actually going to have to properly learn Oracle ;)